# MVVM with Entity Framework Project Structure

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am currently learning MVVM in WPF. I am creating an application that incorporates Entity Framework using Code First approach. What should be the proper structure of my project?

MVVM has this structure

```
Views 
ViewModels
Model
```

My current plan is to put my POCO into the Model folder. Where should I put the class that inherits from the DbContext class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVVM does not specify a service infrastructure per se. While your POCO domain should remain in the "Model" directory the DbContext should not be known to the MVVM implementation.

In other words there shouldn't be a class that derives from DbContext.

I normally provide that type of functionality through a ViewModelProvider construct that abstracts the "actual" model away from the ViewModel implementation. This lends to easier mocking etc. All concrete viewModel implementations should be "provided" through this abstraction.

Comment: Still not clear as to where to place my DbContext class. I know that DbContext is separate with MVVM itself. Should I create an Infrastructure or a DAL project (MyProject.Infrastructure or MyProject.DAL) and put the DbContext and its configurations there? Thanks.

Comment: OK, first I would start by creating a "Service" layer that you can query your model from. Then provide an implementation that binds your model to ViewModels at the application level ("ViewModelProvider"). In other words, your actual DbContext accessors should remain hidden behind a ViewModelProvider abstraction. Does that clear things up? Its hard to lay down specifics in a comment :-)

Comment: Thanks, those are helpful tips. But where should you put your DbContext class. It has to be there somewhere or entity framework will not work.

Comment: Hmm, I think I know where you're problem is now. MVVM is a UI "testable" framework for WPF. Ok, now, your DbContext does not belong inside this framework so where do you "put" it? The answer is outside of WPF in a "Service" layer. Your DbContext should be hidden from MVVM completely. So because MVVM does not define a Service layer you need to implement that yourself. This will include accessing the data and converting the Model objects into ViewModel objects used by the UI. You call this "Service" when you need to build you ViewModels/UI.

Comment: To be honest this question had confused me as well. Primarily due to my little less than "Hello World" exp in WPF. Brilliant answer! It is important to see MVVM as just a presentation system. How you get stuff in that "presentation system" should be handled from outside.

Comment: @bic Is service layer a set of classes that have methods to interact with entity framework datbase context? what else comes in to the service layer. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The Models, Views, and ViewModels buckets are really just layers of your application. Their actual location doesn't matter, so long as the *interactions* between them don't violate the MVVM pattern.

That said, I tend to follow the pattern set by ASP.NET MVC and the T4Scaffolding NuGet package. After installing that package you can issue the following command.

```
Scaffold Repository -ModelType Person
```

This will scaffold two new classes for you based on the Person model class.

- Models\MyApplicationContext.cs
- Models\PersonRepository.cs

The first is just a standard DbContext class like you would expect. It is not inteded that your Views or ViewModles will interact directly with this class. The repository class provides an abstraction over the context; this is the one you should pass around between layers. A repository is also much easier to mock than DbContaxt, and could easily be implemented using a totally different technology like WCF Data Services.

Hopefully this answer at least gives you a good place to start.

Comment: I need information as to where DbContext class be placed and not whether it contribute to the MVVM pattern. Should I just include it in the models folder like what you provide in your example?

Comment: @randacun, that's how I start. As the app evolves, you may find a better place for it (e.g. in a Services layer like bic suggests).

Comment: What is the difference between a service layer and respository?

Comment: @AnkurSharma, you would probably use a [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) inside the [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html). (See links for more details.)